# check-box tic sign is not appearing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

i have no idea why in my mvc application when i do return "true" value to the check-box in view page why its tic sign is not appearing ? need help with this.

view page

```
<div id="maindiv">
<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.status)%>
<%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.status)%>
</div>
```

this is the script to set data to for checkbox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#status').val(true);
   alert(" active " + $('#status').val());
</script>
```

Comment: Do you get a JavaScript error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of *`$('#status').val(true)`* try;

```
$('#status').prop('checked', true); //checked
$('#status').prop('checked', false); //unchecked
```

Or for jQuery 1.5 and below

```
$('#status').attr('checked','checked');
```

Comment: I use `$('#status').attr('checked', true);` and `$('#status').attr('checked', false);` with jQuery 1.7.2

Comment: thnx for the help Kaf.. i am using 1.5 btw :)